# Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070002 Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

Hola estoy trabajando en **Visual** **Studio** y no se que hize ahora que no puedo accesar a los controlladores de mi proyecto, puedo correrlo sin problema pero cuando trato de accesar me aparece lo siguiente ...

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Alguien sabe a qué se pueda deber?

Comment: Has movido los archivos de lugar? o renombrados ? Ese error indica que no puede encontarlos donde estaban ya que fueron movidos, eliminados o renombrados. Verifica eso primeramente

Comment: no, todo está en su lugar ya lo confirmé

Comment: Hola, tu pregunta fue reportada como de "baja calidad", las respuestas no deben usarse para aclaraciones sobre la pregunta. Revisar [asnwer]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Visual Studio no suele tener muchos bugs, pero a veces actúa como un "tonto", por lo que sea tu Visual Studio se ha topado con un bug, la solución que a mí me ha funcionado para estos casos es la de añadir otra vez el archivo (sin haberlo eliminado de la solución) como objeto existente.

Te dejo aquí la ubicación de la opción que te digo, aunque la imagen sea la primera que he encontrado y el visual studio se vea antiguo dicha opción está en el mismo lugar.

[image: imagen de visual studio antigua]

Comment: Súper todo funcionó había perdido acceso a todos mis archivos y con solo añadir uno, recuperé el acceso a todos :D, solo un detalle, al agregar un archivo existente en otra parte, cualquier referencia a ese archivo mandará un error de duplicidad, solo debes eliminar el mismo archivo existente que metiste y no debería haber ningún error y todo funcionará súper :D